# Objective-C Modifying Class Instance Superclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering if there was a way of dynamically taking an Instance of a class, so lets say I have a UIViewController called menu.

I could take menu's superclass which in this case would be UIViewController and create a subclass of it. I would then assign this new subclass to menu, I could also then dynamically override the methods as well.

So that when menu calls a method such as "ButtonClicked:" my code in the new Class I created fires followed by the original code when I call super :).

This all has to be done at runtime for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime subclassing is totally possible. Here's an introduction: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-19-creating-classes-at-runtime-for-fun-and-profit.html

Although I'm curious... what "security" do you think you're getting by subclassing at runtime?

Comment: It's worth noting that this will not actually do anything to help your security.

Comment: I am just doing it to detect the memory address of the implementations  for each method call.

Comment: Why can't you just use `method_getImplementation` for that?

Comment: and how would detecting addresses would help you with security?

Comment: And yeah. Why do you think that this is going to confer any security benefits whatsoever?

Comment: Because if they swizzled out the original method in the class then I could detect it and throw an error the next time that method is called? Since they have only swapped out the method for a particular class so if I dynamically subclass it and route all the calls through it, I can verify the implementation for every call.

Comment: @JamesCampbell: I am not sure that would be effective. Anybody who is able to swizzle the superclass's methods will be able to swizzle your dynamic subclass's methods just as easily. I don't see how anybody who's able to inject code into your app's memory space would be stymied by this at all.

Comment: What if I had a method I called before I called the actual method. IT would see if it had a memory address for the method I'm about to call stored somewhere (Not in Obj-C) and if it has would verify the memory address is the same. If it is then show an error. Every-time a sensitive method call is used in my app, I would do this check (i.e when accessing the user data object)

Comment: I got the feeling, you just made your first steps on a path that's gonna be quite painful… remember that other people's code might use swizzeling for valid reasons (KVO et al). Also we might not know some implementation details that could affect the methods addresses.

Comment: I mean this in the kindest way, but you are wasting your time with this. If someone has managed to inject code into your iOS app, it's all over. Any countermeasure you can take, they can be ahead of you. Plus, maybe I'm stating the obvious, but ASLR is going to prevent you from building in any checks for differences from the compile-time state of your apps. You should find another way to protect your intellectual capital.